# Preference menu in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have been following this [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) tutorial to attempt to add a Preference Fragment to my app. The problem I have is that, although the `PreferenceFragment` displays, there is no action bar and the background is transparent. I ideally want it to look similar the the one in the dev guide.

I've tried adding a `android:background` tag to the `preferences.xml` file as well as making a seperate layout xml file and using

```
`    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,container, false)  ;
        return root;
    }`
```

in the `SettingsFragment.java` file below. (I removed both of these as the app was crashing).

My code is as follows:

`preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- settings menu -->
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_title_sample_size"
        android:key="pref_sample_size"
            >

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_sample_freq"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summery_sample_freq"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_sample_freq"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_total_size"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_total_sample"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_total_sample"
            android:defaultValue="2"
            />

        </PreferenceCategory>
```

`SettingsFragment.java`

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

and the following extract from `MainActivity.java`

```
        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                        .commit();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I am missing?

Comment: The text appears to be overlaid on the MainActivity layout file, I can still press the buttons behind through the gaps in the text

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what do you want, but maybe you want to make `headers` in your activity.
I think you wrong when you choose the menu to `commit()` your `Fragment`.
 You should read this: [Preference Headers from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders)
And also: [Preference Headers Tutorial](http://gmariotti.blogspot.fr/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment_28.html)

Let me know if it helps and if it was that you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add action bar on your preferences, add this on your `SettingsFragment.java` inside `onCreate` :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_preference);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

and outside onCreate method, add :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        SettingsFragment.this.finish();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```